# Default value in column when using lag function in hive/sql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table like below in `Hive`.

I want to calculate the time difference in `seconds` for columns where `id` is same and get the value in `time_diff` column.

`Table`

```
+-----+---------+------------------------+
| id  |  event  |            eventdate   |
+-----+---------+------------------------+
| 1   | sent    | 2017-11-23 03:49:50.0  |
| 1   | sent    | 2017-11-23 03:49:59.0  |
| 2   | sent    | 2017-11-23 04:49:59.0  |
| 1   | click   | 2017-11-24 03:49:50.0  |
+-----+---------+------------------------+
```

I have done like below

```
SELECT *, coalesce(unix_timestamp(eventdate) - unix_timestamp(LAG(eventdate) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY eventdate)),0) time_diff FROM Table;
```

`Result`

```
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| id  |  event  |            eventdate   |time_diff  |
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| 1   | sent    | 2017-11-23 03:49:50.0  | 0         |
| 1   | sent    | 2017-11-23 03:49:59.0  | 9         |
| 2   | sent    | 2017-11-23 04:49:59.0  | 0         |
| 1   | click   | 2017-11-24 03:49:50.0  | 86391     |
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
```

I am getting what I want but with a small exception. In the result where `id` is `1` and `event` is `sent` in the `time_diff` column there are two values `0` and `9`. I want all the `sent` events to have `0` in the `time_diff` column after we apply the lag function.

`Expected result`:

```
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| id  |  event  |            eventdate   |time_diff  |
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
| 1   | sent    | 2017-11-23 03:49:50.0  | 0         |
| 1   | sent    | 2017-11-23 03:49:59.0  | 0         |
| 2   | sent    | 2017-11-23 04:49:59.0  | 0         |
| 1   | click   | 2017-11-24 03:49:50.0  | 86391     |
+-----+---------+------------------------+-----------+
```

How can I get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT *,
       (case when event = 'sent' then 0
             else coalesce(unix_timestamp(eventdate) - unix_timestamp(LAG(eventdate) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY eventdate)), 0)
        end) as time_diff 
FROM Table;
```